# BIGINT datatype in mysql giving error at the time of creating table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a table and to column assign i assigned a datatype BIGINIT it giving a error 
"The given datatype BIGINT() contain errors and can not be accepted."

I am using mysql workbench 6.3 CE

Comment: which commands did you try? Please post all your `endeavors`.

Comment: I am creating table by add table option not using command

Comment: Look `BIGINIT` is not the correct datatype. The correct form should be `BIGINT`.

Comment: yes sorry it is BIGINT,my type mistek in question

Comment: Are you specifying it as `BIGINT()` or just `BIGINT`.  It won't let you specify it with empty braces

Comment: it is taking BIGINT() atomatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove brackets, you are specifying round brackets which are not needed.
Right syntax is as follows:

Use only `BIGINT`

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the brackets and it works fine. It also gives you a cursor right next to those brackets after selection from drop down list,use backspace.
It takes an integer of `length < 20` by default.